# JDODetachedFieldAccessException: You have just attempted to access field "attachment" yet this field was not detached when you detached the object

Tags: jpa, datanucleus, detach, lob

Entity class:

```
public class CustomerSurvey implements Serializable {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
   generator="CUSTOMER_SURVEY_SEQUENCE")
@Column(name = "SURVEYID", nullable = false)
private String surveyId;



@Column(name="ATTACHMENT")
@Lob
private byte[] attachment;
....
```

Persistence class/logic:

```
 public List<CustomerSurvey> getSurveysByCustomer(String custNo)
        throws WorkServiceException {
    EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("customerSurvey.findByCustomer")
            .setParameter("custNo", custNo);
    logger.debug(query);
    List<CustomerSurvey> surveys = query.getResultList();
    em.clear();
    em.close();
    return surveys;
}
```

consumer class/logic:

```
   List<CustomerSurvey> reviewSurveys = workService.getSurveysByCustomer("testCNo2");
    for(CustomerSurvey rsurvey: reviewSurveys) {
        Object obj = rsurvey.getAttachment();
        byte[] buffer = (byte[]) obj;
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Temp\\TulipsOut.jpg");
        out.write(buffer);
    }
```

Error I get as:

Caused by: javax.jdo.JDODetachedFieldAccessException: You have just attempted to access field "attachment" yet this field was not detached when you detached the object. Either dont access this field, or detach it when detaching the obj
ect.
        at com.ge.dsp.iwork.entity.CustomerSurvey.jdoGetattachment(CustomerSurvey.java)
        at com.ge.dsp.iwork.entity.CustomerSurvey.getAttachment(CustomerSurvey.java:89)
        at com.ge.dsp.iwork.test.WorkServiceTest.testSubmitSurveyResponse(WorkServiceTest.java:270)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1581)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1522)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
        ... 14 more

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main problem is `private byte[] attachment;`.

1. The default loading of `@Log` attribute will be `FetchType.LAZY`.
2. The `Persistence Context` will be clear after the `clear()` process of `EntityManager`. That mean all of the managed entities will become detached state. More Information is [here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/managed).
3. When an `Entity` is detached state, if you access fetching value, you will get the problem as you mention.

**Short Answer :**

After `em.clear()` process, your entity instance `surveys` will be detached. That's why, you cannot retrieve the value `attachment` because of `attachment` is lazy loading(`FetchType.LAZY`).

**Solution :** use `FetchType.EAGER`. I think, most of the people don't recommend to use eager loading.

```
    @Column(name="ATTACHMENT")
    @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Lov
    private byte[] attachment;
```

Comment: thank you that works. I m new to JPA. When we say eager loading is not recommend, then what is the alternate approach in such case? how do I get/load those information when needed?

Comment: @beetri, I am sorry for "I think, most of the people don't recommend to use eager loading." It can be my lack of experience. The main is, if you would like to get `CustomerSurvey` together with `attachment`, use `EAGER`. Otherwise, use `LAZY`. Reference : http://www.melihsakarya.com/2011/12/jpa-fetch-stratejileri-ve-lazy-loading/